# Merge values of two JSON Array into a JSONObject java

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, rx-java2

I have JSON Arrays in this form:

```
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

[122402538, 12240345, 122496, 122617, 1227473, 1228495]
```

Now i want to merge each `Long` value with the other, keeping intact its index, like this:

```
[{"id": 6, "timestamp":122402538}, {"id": 7, "timestamp": 12240345}, {"id": , "timestamp": 12240345},...]
```

I have tried to loop and then add the values into a `JSONObject` like this:

```
JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("theFirstArray");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
jo = array.getLong(i);
jsonObject.put("id", jo);
jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
}

JSONArray timestamp = object.getJSONArray("theSecondArray");
 for (int i = 0; i < timestamp .length(); i++){
 Long jos = timestamp .getLong(i);
 jsonObject.put("timeStamp", jos);
 jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
}
```

But, unfortunately, its the last values that are `put` into the array.

How do i merge both values of both arrays into one `JSONObject`, then have a list of all those `JSONObjects`?.

I have looked at other questions, even from the *phps*, *javascripts*, none have helped.

Or is there a way to do this using **RxJava2**?.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's combine both array using RxJava

```
JSONArray combinedArray = new JSONArray();


    List<Integer> idList = Arrays.asList(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);
    List<Integer> timestampList = Arrays.asList(122402538, 12240345, 122496, 122617, 1227473, 1228495);

    final int[] counter = {0}; // assuming your both array are of same size.
    Observable.fromIterable(idList)
            .map(id -> {
                        JSONObject singleObject = new JSONObject();
                        singleObject.put("id:", id);
                        singleObject.put("timestamp:", timestampList.get(counter[0]));
                        counter[0]++;
                        combinedArray.put(singleObject);
                        return Observable.just(combinedArray);
                    }
            )
            .toList()  //jsonArrayObservable is observable json array, if you want to your later on
            .doOnSuccess(jsonArrayObservable -> Log.d("jsonArrayObservable -> ", combinedArray.toString()))
            .subscribe();
```

> **OUTPUT**

```
 jsonArrayObservable -> :[{"id:":6,"timestamp:":122402538},{"id:":7,"timestamp:":12240345},{"id:":8,"timestamp:":122496},{"id:":9,"timestamp:":122617},{"id:":10,"timestamp:":1227473},{"id:":11,"timestamp:":1228495}]
```

**UPDATE without support of java 8**

```
Observable.fromIterable(idList)
            .map(new Function<Integer, Object>() {
                     @Override
                     public Object apply(Integer id) throws Exception {
                         JSONObject singleObject = new JSONObject();
                         singleObject.put("id:", id);
                         singleObject.put("timestamp:", timestampList.get(counter[0]));
                         counter[0]++;
                         combinedArray.put(singleObject);
                         return Observable.just(combinedArray);
                     }
                 }
            )
            .toList()  //jsonArrayObservable is observable json array, if you want to your later on
            .doOnSuccess(jsonArrayObservable -> Log.d("jsonArrayObservable -> ", combinedArray.toString()))
            .subscribe();
```

> Output

[image]

Comment: Apologies for the long silence, i had to install Java 8... had some issues. Yes, i have tried it, this is the result i get `D/jsonArrayObservable ->: [{"id:":[6,7,8,9,10,11,12]}, {"timeStamp:"[ 122402538, 12240345, 122496, 122617, 1227473, 1228495] } ]`. The arrays are of the same size.

Comment: check updated code to run same without java 8 support. and what do you mean by result you get? Try again.. the output should be the same as I have mentioned in answer and accept this answer if it works for you.

Comment: I have tried it.. Observation: I have the `Long` values in a `JSONArray`, so i believe the `JSONArray` might be affecting merging both values, Is there a workaround to that, i mean how to use the above code, with a `List` of `Long` values that are in a JSONArray.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one written in Java and the [vaadin](http://vaadin.com/download/release/7.2/7.2.2/docs/api/com/google/gwt/dev/jjs/ast/js/JsonObject.html) library I assume you're using.

Code:

```
    long timeStamps[] = {122402538, 12240345, 122496, 122617, 1227473, 1228495};
    long array[] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put( "id:", array[i]);
        jsonObject.put("timestamp:", timeStamps[i]);
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
    }

    System.out.println(jsonArray);
    // prints [{"id:":6,"timestamp:":122402538},{"id:":7,"timestamp:":12240345},{"id:":8,"timestamp:":122496},{"id:":9,"timestamp:":122617},{"id:":10,"timestamp:":1227473},{"id:":11,"timestamp:":1228495}]
```

Sorry for not posting in RxJava2, I don't know how to.

Hope this helps anyway.

---

**edit**:

Using Google's gson:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class jsonExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long timeStamps[] = {122402538, 12240345, 122496, 122617, 1227473, 1228495};
        long array[] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
        JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();

        for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
            jsonObject.addProperty("id:", array[i]);
            jsonObject.addProperty("timestamp:", timeStamps[i]);
            jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
        }

        System.out.println(jsonArray);
        // prints [{"id:":6,"timestamp:":122402538},{"id:":7,"timestamp:":12240345},{"id:":8,"timestamp:":122496},{"id:":9,"timestamp:":122617},{"id:":10,"timestamp:":1227473},{"id:":11,"timestamp:":1228495}]
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using Vaadin library, is there a gradle implementation?. and when i run the above implementation, i get the `array type expected, found: org.json.JSONArray`

Comment: Sure, [Gradle plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.devsoap.plugin.vaadin).
I'll also be happy to help if you already use some other library.

Comment: I use `org.json.JSONArray` and `gson` library. Is there any workaround using those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 JSONArray array1 = object.getJSONArray("theFirstArray");
    JSONArray array2 = object.getJSONArray("thesecondarray");
    JSONObject finalObject=new JSONObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
        jo.put("id",array1.get(i));
        jo.put("timestamp",array2.get(i));
        finalObject.put(jo);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but i still keep getting the last values of both arrays into the object.